Is there way to get the name of the user that merged a pull request
I know it is possible to get the name of the user who created a pull request using GitHub Rest API but is it possible to get the name of the user who merged/approved a pull request ?
I tried using postman to see if there's any information about but i couldn't find any. Maybe I am using the wrong API. Here's what I use to get the pull requests: "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls?state={state}&per_page=100"

"List Pull Requests" API does not provide information about the user who merged each pull request.
You can use "Get Pull Request" API to find this information for each pull request:
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}

It contains a 'merged_by' object:
    {
      "merged_by": {
        "login": "octocat",
        "id": 1,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
        "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      }
    }

